# Remote PS Command with Output

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Good afternoon all.

Let me start off by saying I appreciate all the assistance whenever I ask a question, and I promise I am trying to brush up on my PS, but it's a lot slower than I thought it would be.

However, your answer assistance helps me put together and modify scripts that I need for my environment as well. :-)

I need to know how to do the following.

I need to know how to load all servers from A/D, and then run the following command:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |
  Where-Object { $_.Publisher -contains "AUTHOR" } |
    Select-Object DisplayName, $PSPath
```

That command on a server would result in the following as an example:

[image: RegKey Results]

Some A/D joined servers could have less, some could have more.

Then it would write the file to either a comma or other some sort of delimited file.

with the server name (either A/D Common Name, or FQDN), and those lines of results.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction of how to get started with that, and then I can modify it later as needed.

I have tried the following, and it keeps prompting for "process[0]:", so obviously I have something in the wrong place:

```
import-csv C:\Temp\computerlisting.csv |    
  foreach {
    $ScriptBlock = {Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |
      Where-Object { $_.Publisher -contains "AUTHOR" } |
        Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion}
     
    Invoke-command -ComputerName $_.name -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
    
  }

$result
```

Thank you again!

Comment: The foreach and `{` have to be on the same line.  Also -contains only does whole word matches.  You can invoke-command an array of computernames and run in parallel.  See also the get-package command.  $result is not set.